# How do i display data from Ajax Get Method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to display the data I retrieved from my Controller, and I can see the data on my Browser's console but it wont display in html. Here is my code:

```
    function GetUserInfo() {
        var username = readCookie("Cookie");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/getInfo/' + username,
            type: 'GET',
            data: { UserName: 'UserName', FirstName: 'FirstName', LastName: 'LastName' },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function( Results ) {
                if (Results.length > 0) {

                     $('#username').text(Results.UserName);
$('#firstname').text(Results.UserName);
$('#lastname').text(Results.UserName);

                }
                else {
                    alert( "No data." );
                }
            }

        }).fail(
            function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        );
    }
```

This is the data I need to display:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "UserName": "demouser",
        "FirstName": "Demo",
        "LastName": "User",
        "EmailAddress": "demo.user@mail.com",
        "PhoneNumber": "xxx-xxx-xxxx"
    }
]
```

This is the server side code i use to display my data:

```
public List<Models.User> GetUserInfo( String username )
{
    List<Models.User> UserInfo = null;
    var Info = from m in db.MstUsers
               where m.UserName == username
               select new Models.User
               {
                   UserName = m.UserName,
                   FirstName = m.FirstName,
                   LastName = m.LastName,
                   EmailAddress = m.EmailAddress,
                   PhoneNumber = m.PhoneNumber
               };

    UserInfo = Info.ToList();
    return UserInfo;
}
```

How do I store the variables in the *data* option? What is the correct way to place data from an array? I am new to JQuery. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code and help me understand the proper way to store data?

Comment: Could you show an example of the data? Either it's an object in which case it won't have a `.length` property, or it's an array in which case it won't have a `.UserName` property.

Comment: Can you add your server side code please? Would help a lot to see what kind of data this is

Comment: Yes, that's an array so you'll have to specify which element you're referring to (`Results[0].UserName` and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Results` is an array. You must either iterate and show the data in your DOM else use index `Results[0]`(if its first element, change index based on the object you want to show) to show the results.

In case `$("#username")` is an input text field, use `$("#username").va(Results[0].username)` instead.

```
success: function( Results ) {
                if (Results.length > 0) {

                     $('#username').text(Results[0].UserName);
                     $('#firstname').text(Results[0].UserName);
                     $('#lastname').text(Results[0].UserName);

                }
                else {
                    alert( "No data." );
                }
            }
```